# Passing input value into name of input

Tags: forms, input

I'm trying to get the value from two input fields and pass them as the name in a form.

In my code, I am hardcoding the value of the price range in for testing purposes.

```
            echo 'PRICE RANGE:';
            echo 'Low: <input type="text" name="t[pr_100000]" value="" maxlength="25" /> High: <input type="text" name="t[ph_10000000]" value="" maxlength="25" />';

            echo 'STATUS:';
           $termsStatus = get_terms( 'Status', array(
                  'hide_empty' => 0
                  ) );
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach ($termsStatus as $term_st) {
                    $termsStatus = $term_st->name . 'PropertyFilter';
                    echo '<li><label><input type="checkbox" name="t[st_' . $term_st->name . ']"  value="st_">' .$term_st->name. '</label></li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
```

Any suggetions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi graphical_force, this is a PHP question and would be better asked over on http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Sure, is this something I could move myself? If so, how would i do it? Thanks!

Comment: A moderator can move it, though they might be asleep:)

Comment: Understood. It's about bedtime for me as well. I check in the morning. Thanks again!